# Confused with jQuery multi-layered dynamic tabs. Can't work out what to do

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, dynamic, tabs

Okay here's a very simplified version of what I'm trying to achieve.

First layer of tabs[ft]: 1, 2, 3, 4.

Second layer: [ft]a, [ft]b, [ft]c, [ft]d. Some of these will be hidden.

When the user selects the first tab, the second layer of tabs should be re/loaded according to the first tab they chose and the content of a html file.

The values stating which tabs will be shown and hidden comes from a html file. I'm not sure how to format it.

For example: I open the page, and select tab 2.

The content of tab 2 will load, revealing another set of tabs which are unique to tab 2. The html file says to show tab 2a, 2b and 2d so those tabs are shown, the others are hidden.

Sorry if you don't understand, I'm really struggling figuring out where to start in this.

Here's some messy existing code:

```
    <div id="firsttabs" class="firsttabs">
                          <ul>
                            <li><a href="#1" onclick="event.preventDefault();"><img id="1" style="display:none" src="images/1.png"/></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#2" onclick="event.preventDefault();"><img id="2" style="display:none" src="images/2.png" /></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#3" onclick="event.preventDefault();"><img id="3" style="display:none" src="images/3.png" /></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#4" onclick="event.preventDefault();"><img id="4" style="display:none" src="images/4.png" /></a></li>
                          </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div id="secondtabs">
                            <div id="1">    
                                <div id="secondtabs1" class="secondtabs1">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="#1a" onclick="event.preventDefault()"><img style="display:none" id="1a" src="images/1a.png" /></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#2a" onclick="event.preventDefault()"><img style="display:none"  id="2a" src="images/2a.png" /></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#3a" onclick="event.preventDefault()"><img style="display:none"  id="3a"  src="images/3a.png"/></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#4a" onclick="event.preventDefault()"><img style="display:none"  id="4a"  src="images/4a.png"/></a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>  
                                <div id="content">
                                    <div id="1a">Content1a</div>
                                    <div id="2a">Content2a</div>
                                    <div id="3a">Content3a</div>
                                    <div id="4a">Content4a</div>
                                    <div id="5a">Content5a</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="2">Content2</div>
                            <div id="secondtabs2" class="secondtabs2">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="#1a" onclick="event.preventDefault()"><img style="display:none" id="1a" src="images/1a.png" /></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#2a" onclick="event.preventDefault()"><img style="display:none"  id="2a" src="images/2a.png" /></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#3a" onclick="event.preventDefault()"><img style="display:none"  id="3a"  src="images/3a.png"/></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#4a" onclick="event.preventDefault()"><img style="display:none"  id="4a"  src="images/4a.png"/></a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>  
                                <div id="content">
                                    <div id="1b">Content1a</div>
                                    <div id="2b">Content2a</div>
                                    <div id="3b">Content3a</div>
                                    <div id="4b">Content4a</div>
                                    <div id="5b">Content5a</div>
                                </div>
                            <div id="3">More tabs...</div>

                            <div id="4">More tabs...</div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
```

As you can see it's less than ideal.

EDIT: Ignore any html errors in this code as I just did this for demonstation purposes.

Comment: please show your jquery code. Also are you using a plugin for the tabs?

Comment: It's incredibly messy, I'll try and clean it up and put it up tomorrow.

Comment: And I'd rather a better method than this if there's one.

Comment: is there a site that has an example you are trying to emulate?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. This is what I'm working on http://www.theowindebank.co.uk/jailbreak/ type in iphone 2g and 1.1, and I want it to show which os's it can be jailbroken and which software.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example (and code) of using nested tabs:
http://jsfiddle.net/R5sSh/

This is using the [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) plugin.

Comment: You can obviously skin that any way you want, and add as many different layers of content and tabs as you want, and the jQuery is only two function calls.